# What's the meaning of a highlighted side ops with a dot on the left side?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Some side ops (missions) in the MGSV:TPP stay highlighted with a dot on the left side, even after the mission was done. What does that means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are repeatable side-ops. You can play them again to earn GMP and heroism, should you choose to do so (although this is probably not the most time efficient way to earn either). Side-ops will respawn when there is not a new side-op active in that segment of the map.

Comment: This is not exactly what OP is asking for. Repeatable missions are not greyed out after completion, just get a completion mark besides. He's asking about a dot beside mission name.

Comment: He's asking about them reappearing after completion, which is what I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a white/yellow (with yellow being "more important" kind) dot on the left side of a mission means it has just appeared (same goes to tapes/staff/etc.).

Considering you have already finished that mission I would classify this as a minor glitch/bug.

Another possibility is that you haven't (for example) extracted all possible valuable targets from given mission and the game simply notifies you of this fact.